# How to integrate the iframe of the Facebook page plugin in Odoo 8

Tags: iframe, odoo-8, odoo, facebook-iframe, iframe-app

I tried to integrate the plugin page of the Facebook in my XML file (I am working with Odoo 8 ) for the page : https://www.facebook.com/kissabebe

like this :

```
<form string="Embedded Webpage" version="7.0" edit="false" create="false"> 
  <div style="position:absolute; left:0; top:0; width:100%; height:100%;"> 
    <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/page.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fkissabebe&tabs=timeline&width=350&height=250&small_header=true&adapt_container_width=true&hide_cover=false&show_facepile=true&appId=164011430896983" sanitize="False" width="100%" height="100%" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" frameborder="no" scrolling="no" style="border-width:0px;"></iframe> 
  </div> 
</form>
```

But I have errors. Can you correct me please?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`&amp;` might be the issue. Try replacing `&` to `&amp;`